# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v2' has no attribute '__internal__'

Tags: tensorflow

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape, y_test.shape)

im = plt.imshow(x_train[0], cmap="gray")
plt.show()


x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784)

x_train = x_train/255
x_test = x_test/255

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=SGD(), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

I tried several different versions of the combination, but still reported an error about
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v2' has no attribute '**internal**'

Comment: I am facing the same issue, idk how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v2' has no attribute '__internal__'
```

Generally you will get above error due to incompatibility between `Tensorflow` and `Keras`. You can import `keras` without any issues by upgrade to latest version. For more details you can refer this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67817124/14290681).

Coming to your code, have couple of issues and it can be resolved

1.`to_categorical` has now packed in `np_utils`. You need to add import as shown below

```
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
```

2.Typo mistake, replace `metics` to `metrics` in `model.compile`

Working code as shown below

```
import keras
print(keras.__version__)
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical


(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape, y_test.shape)

im = plt.imshow(x_train[0], cmap="gray")
plt.show()


x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784)

x_train = x_train/255
x_test = x_test/255

y_train = to_categorical(y_train, 10) 
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, 10)   

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=SGD(), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Output:

```
2.5.0
(60000, 28, 28) (60000,)
(10000, 28, 28) (10000,)

Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 512)               401920    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               131328    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                2570      
=================================================================
Total params: 535,818
Trainable params: 535,818
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/5
938/938 [==============================] - 21s 8ms/step - loss: 1.2351 - accuracy: 0.6966 - val_loss: 0.3644 - val_accuracy: 0.9011
Epoch 2/5
938/938 [==============================] - 7s 7ms/step - loss: 0.3554 - accuracy: 0.9023 - val_loss: 0.2943 - val_accuracy: 0.9166
Epoch 3/5
938/938 [==============================] - 7s 7ms/step - loss: 0.2929 - accuracy: 0.9176 - val_loss: 0.2553 - val_accuracy: 0.9282
Epoch 4/5
938/938 [==============================] - 7s 7ms/step - loss: 0.2538 - accuracy: 0.9281 - val_loss: 0.2309 - val_accuracy: 0.9337
Epoch 5/5
938/938 [==============================] - 7s 8ms/step - loss: 0.2313 - accuracy: 0.9355 - val_loss: 0.2096 - val_accuracy: 0.9401
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f615c82d090>
```

You can refer this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/chunduriv/ec032316e81f08a040848783e5822c00/keras.ipynb),for the above use case in tensorflow version.

Answer (score 0):

**Error:**

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v2' has no attribute '__internal__'
```

***Solution:***

Install Libraries

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.1
!pip install keras==2.3.1
```

Import

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```