# module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v2' has no attribute '__internal__'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am using `python 3.6.9` , `keras 2.3.1`, and (`tf 2.0.0` or `tf 2.1.0`).
Got the compatibility versions from this [table](https://docs.floydhub.com/guides/environments/).

When I import keras I get this error.

[image]

Comment: @M.Innat ImportError: cannot import name 'kreas'

Answer (score 5):

**Error:**

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v2' has no attribute '__internal__'
```

***Solution:***

Install Libraries

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.1
!pip install keras==2.3.1
```

Import

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate your issue with the below combination as shown below

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.1.0
!pip install keras==2.3.1
import keras
```

Output:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-88d96843a926> in <module>()
----> 1 import keras

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/initializers/__init__.py in populate_deserializable_objects()
     47 
     48   LOCAL.ALL_OBJECTS = {}
---> 49   LOCAL.GENERATED_WITH_V2 = tf.__internal__.tf2.enabled()
     50 
     51   # Compatibility aliases (need to exist in both V1 and V2).

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v2' has no attribute '__internal__'
```

**Fixed code:**

Here issue is due to incompatibility between `TF2.1` and `Keras 2.3.1`. Your issue can be resolved in two ways

1. Upgrade to `Keras2.5.0rc0` and `import keras`
2. import keras from tensorflow as `from tensorflow import keras`

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar error while trying to import Tokenizer from keras.preprocessing

This caused error -

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
```

**This fixed it-**

```
from tensorflow.keras import preprocessing
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
```