# module 'tensorflow.python.keras.backend' has no attribute 'slice'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement https://github.com/ec-jrc/GHS-S2Net this project (in google colab). A week ago it was working by installing the requirements:

```
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0
!pip install Keras==2.3.1
```

Unfortunately, from this week it is showing me `module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v2' has no attribute '__internal__'` for `import keras`.
Ok, I wanted to try with the latest versions of tensor and keras (both 2.5.0), but now I am getting following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.backend' has no attribute 'slice'
```

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.backend' has no
> attribute 'slice'

It looks like an installation issue. Please try to uninstall and reinstall Keras

```
pip uninstall keras
pip install keras --upgrade
```

> module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v2' has no attribute '**internal**'

Due to incompatibility between `Tensorflow` and `Keras` you get this issue.

As mentioned above, if you upgrade to latest keras version and `import keras` or import keras from tensorflow as `from tensorflow import keras` will resolve this issue. For more information you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67817124/14290681).

Answer (score 0):

Keras.backend doesnt have a slice operation. Instead, you can go to the location where the `crf.py` file is stored locally on your machine (this you can find mentioned in the error dialogue, i.e.(myenv\Lib\site-packages\keras_contrib\layers\crf.py) and do the following:

add the line --> `import tensorflow as tf`.
Goto line number where it is mentioned K.slice,
It is in the function: `def step(self, input_energy_t, states, return_logZ=True`.

You can do a search for "slice".
Then replace `K.slice` by `tf.slice`.

Restart the jupyter notebook session. This should work.

Answer (score -1):

Change the line 463 in crf.py as import tensorflow as tf; tf.slice. Then save the crf.py.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).