# Attribute AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2' has no attribute '_internal_'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, carla

Following the CARLA tutorials, I created a file to train my model; however, whenever I try to run it using Command prompt, this error shows up:

```
2021-06-20 19:39:30.429984: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2021-06-20 19:39:30.430242: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CARtut5.py", line 10, in <module>
    from keras.applications.xception import Xception
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\_init_.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import initializers
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers\_init_.py", line 124, in <module>
    populate_deserializable_objects()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers\_init_.py", line 49, in populate_deserializable_objects
    LOCAL.GENERATED_WITH_V2 = tf._internal_.tf2.enabled()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2' has no attribute '_internal_'
```

I tried to uninstall `Keras` and `TensorFlow` and reinstall them, but the error persists.

Comment: What version of python and tensorflow are you using? Try to revert to an older version of tf, that might help.

Comment: Yes, did that and things got running! Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

From comments

> Try to revert to an older version of `tf`, that might help
> (paraphrased from StarShine)

Actually the above issue was due to incompatibility between latest `Tensorflow` version and standalone `Keras`. For more information you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67817124/14290681).